# TField's Origin property meaning

Tags: delphi, tfield

I have a doubt about the `TField`'s `Origin` property.

The [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TField_Origin.html) states:

> `Origin` is only assigned at design time by the Fields editor, and only
>   when the field component is used by a `TQuery` object. The `Origin`
>   property distinguishes the name of the field as it appears in its
>   dataset from the name of the field in the base table on which it is
>   based. For example, in a query that uses the following SQL statement,
>   the value of `Origin` is `CUSTOMER.CUSTNO`.
>
> ```
> SELECT CUSTNO AS ID FROM CUSTOMER
> ```
>
> In this case, the `FieldName` property is ID.
>
> Note: `Origin` is not available on Linux. The `Origin` property is only implemented for BDE-enabled > datasets, which appear only in the Windows product.

But what if the SQL text contains table aliases?

```
SELECT C.CUSTNO AS ID FROM CUSTOMER C
```

Should I expect `Origin` value to be `CUSTOMER.CUSTNO` or should it be `C.CUSTNO`?

Background explanation:

I am using a DevExpress `TcxDBFilterControl` which uses the field's `Origin` property (in the `TcxDBFilterControl.GetExpressionFieldName`, i.e. `if Origin <> ''`) instead of the `FieldName` property, for composing an SQL condition text. The `TpFIBDataSet` sets `Origin` to `CUSTOMER.CUSTNO` instead of `C.CUSTNO`, so I am wondering if it is a `TpFIBDataSet` problem (which should have set `Origin` to `C.CUSTNO`) or if it is a `TcxDBFilterControl` problem (which is not considering that one might have aliases in the SQL text).

Comment: Here it is the name of the field in the base table. So `CUSTNO` at least for Firedac sourced fields from a FDQuery.

Comment: Unless you use BDE you can except nothing. The docs are clear. Why wont you try it yourself?

Comment: @kobik: I try to explain how I came out with this question....
I am using a DevExpress `TcxDBFilterControl` which (in the `TcxDBFilterControl.GetExpressionFieldName`) uses the field's `Origin`, if <> '', instead of the `FieldName`, for composing an SQL condition text. The `TpFIBDataSet` sets the `Origin` with `CUSTOMER.CUSTNO` instead of `C.CUSTNO`, so I'm wondering if it's a `TpFIBDataSet` problem (which should have set the `Origin` to `C.CUSTNO`) or if it is a `TcxDBFilterControl` problem (which is not considering that one might have aliases in the SQL text).

Comment: An alias contrasts with origin. I mean literally. Conceptually, I'd think TpFIBDataSet to be doing the correct naming.